# Optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

Hi Anyone can help me to optimize this query 
in case given that the category table contains 1 million record

```
SELECT a.title, a.item_id, b.image_path 
FROM category c INNER JOIN items a USING(item_id)
INNER JOIN images b USING(item_id)
where cat_id=(select cat_id from category where item_id=1)
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY item_id DESC
limit 10;
```

Comment: Why do you use the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`? You are `SELECT ... FROM category c` anyways. So I think you can just use `WHERE item_id=1` instead of `where cat_id=(select cat_id from category where item_id=1)`. In addition to this, its a bit difficult to 'optimize' something without knowing what you are trying to achieve, what to optimize for and how the database schema looks...

Answer (score 0):

cat_id in your where clause is from what table ?

guess you can use some like:

```
SELECT 
    a.title, 
    a.item_id,
    b.image_path 
FROM 
    items a, 
    images b, 
    category c 
WHERE 
    a.item_id=b.item_id
AND 
    c.item_id = 1
ORDER BY 
    a.item_id DESC
```

Comment: still missing the connection between table c and a.